# Drawing synteny using CIRCOS from progressive MAUVE alignment

Tags: python, circos, java, mauve

I am using Mauve app to align two whole genomes. I've aligned these genomes (gbk files) with the progressive Mauve aligner, and I got sp.sslist, sp.xmfa, sp.guide_tree,sp.backbone file, sp.bbcols etc file. I'm trying to generate a circos plot from MAUVE output. However, The output file format is different from the format required for CIRCOS. Here is the
output of sp.backbone:

```
seq0_leftend    seq0_rightend   seq1_leftend    seq1_rightend
-14446737   -14446957   89204   89424
-14446680   -14446734   89445   89499
```

but the CIRCOS input format is different,  as shown here:

```
chr - hs1 1 0 249250621 chr1
chr - hs2 2 0 243199373 chr2
chr - hs3 3 0 198022430 chr3
```

I want to draw synteny in a similar way as this example figure, which containg contigs of two chromosomes. Kindly help; I am new to python and all. A python script would be a great help for me. Thanks
[image]

Comment: What research have you done? Various tutorials exist, e.g. [here](https://www.royfrancis.com/beautiful-circos-plots-in-r/). Your Mauve backbone file does not look like what that tutorial shows as expected input. I am not a Mauve person but I am pretty sure you want the alignment file output. https://darlinglab.org/mauve/user-guide/files.html